# Node bin file not being recognized on linux or osx

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

I've been developing a node cli app using PyCharm from Windows and it works only on Windows, but always returns `: No such file or directory` when being run from Linux. I've been able to reproduce the issue using a fairly basic example as a test. Try installing each version and notice how the one published from Windows fails to run on Linux or OSX.

Published from Windows: `npm -g install cli-test@1.0.0 && cli-test`

Published from Linux: `npm -g install cli-test@2.0.0 && cli-test`

**package.json:**

```
{
    "name": "cli-test",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "bin": {
        "cli-test": "./cli.js"
    }
}
```

**cli.js**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
console.log('hello world!');
```

If I write this code and then install it using `sudo npm -g install` from the project directory on Linux then run `cli-test` it throws the error mentioned above. If I do the same from windows it console logs properly.

I can get it to work on Linux by using the following steps:

1. Open the project directory on Linux
2. Rename `cli.js` to `cli.old.js`
3. Create a new file called `cli.js`
4. Copy the content of the old file to the new file

**Why won't it run on Linux when I publish to npm from Windows without manually recreating the file from Linux?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows-based line endings are killing you.  The full error says, `env: node\r: No such file or directory` because Windows puts in the \r there (as part of \r\n for newlines), but Linux and OSX just use \n for newlines.

There's an ongoing discussion on NPM's github Issues on this, as well as several possible workarounds: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2097

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that issue, I would have never stumbled upon it on my own. Very frustrating to deal with and track down the issue otherwise.

Comment: It turns out I can set my entire project to use LF line seperators and I changed the default from within pycharm.

Comment: I also develop using Windows and bumped into the same problem when installing in linux :no such file or directory when running bin file. This post saves me heaps after looking crazily for answer 3 days on the net! Npm should mention on their docs: warning when running npm publish from Windows